# How to use "plateau" as a verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does using "plateau" to express "remained constant" in the sentence below make sense?

> Their salary **plateaued** for 3 years.

Comment: Yes. English is pretty flexible in "verbalizing" nouns.

Comment: To *plateau* is not to *remain* constant, but to *become* more constant. You have not provided enough information about the situation for us to say whether *plateau* would be appropraite or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Plateau](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plateau):*** (intransitive verb)

> - to reach a level, period, or condition of stability or maximum attainment

(M-W)

Usage examples:

> The 2016 paper in Nature found that the maximum reported age of death increased until the mid-1990s, then plateaued.
>
> Morningstar’s Hottovy thinks that the market for new members may be plateauing, and that Amazon is now focused on increasing what current Prime users spend rather than recruiting new ones.